# SQL function to generate UUID, update nested jsonb in table with it, and return it

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb, supabase

I'm learning SQL and I'm running into an issue trying to use a local variable in a SQL function and update some jsonb. I would like to have a function that:

- accepts a row id (the primary key for the table) and some properties (jsonb)
- generates a UUID (as a local variable?)
- puts the UUID into the properties jsonb
- inserts the properties jsonb at the end of a nested array in a jsonb column of the table
- returns the UUID

I'm obviously not understanding local variables or functions with multiple commands, but this is my attempt:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_object(main_id uuid, props jsonb)
RETURNS uuid
SECURITY INVOKER
AS $$
  -- The local variable for the UUID, to be returned.  Wrong syntax for local variable?
  SELECT uuid_generate_v4() as new_id

  -- Put the UUID in props.  Can you do this with an input parameter?
  -- Currently fails to compile here with "syntax error at or near "props""
  props = jsonb_set(props, STRING_TO_ARRAY ('id', ','), props, true)

  -- Put the props in the "data" column at the end of the nested "objects" array
  UPDATE "sites"
  SET
    data = jsonb_set(data, STRING_TO_ARRAY ('objects' || ',' || jsonb_array_length(data->'objects'), ','), props, true)
  WHERE id = main_id

  -- Return the UUID
  RETURN new_id
$$
LANGUAGE sql;
```

A solution in plpgsql would also be fine. I'm currently using supabase, but I'm defining the function manually instead of with their SQL function editor, as it doesn't seem to have all the functionality I need for this.  Any help or suggestions is much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Variables can only be used in PL/pgSQL

Comment: ah!  thank you, with that help I was able to get this working in plpgsql:

```
DECLARE
    new_id uuid;
BEGIN
    new_id := gen_random_uuid();

    props = jsonb_set(props, STRING_TO_ARRAY('id', ','), to_jsonb(new_id), true);

    UPDATE "sites"
    SET
        data = jsonb_set(data, STRING_TO_ARRAY('objects' || ',' || jsonb_array_length(data->'objects'), ','), props, true)
    WHERE id = main_id;

    RETURN new_id;
END;
```